# how to display the database table names list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to display the database table names list in CodeIgniter using given syntax:

```
$tables=$this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '%Demo%'");
```

Comment: i have table names like  abc_table1,abc_table2,xyz_table1,and xyz_table2  .i can get result using above query,but i not sure about how to display the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the `database name`.

Check this,

```
SHOW TABLES FROM `database-name` LIKE '%a%'
```

See mysql documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html)

To get table names,

```
 $tables=$this->db->query("SELECT t.TABLE_NAME AS myTables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name' AND t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%a%' ")->result_array();    
 foreach($tables as $key => $val) {
      echo $val['myTables']."<br>";// myTables is the alias used in query.
 }
```

Comment: yes ,i got result ,but how to display in dropdown box

Comment: @DhiNa, check the edit, you have to modify the query little bit.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

```
$tables = $this->db->list_tables();

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
   echo $table;
}
```

[documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/table_data.html)

Comment: i need to get selected tables name having some prefix values

Answer (score 3):

Try with `information_schema.tables`

Example:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE **** ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Go through this [Chapter 19 `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

**EDIT 01**

```
$this->db->list_tables();
$this->db->like('name', 'field');
```

Comment: i need next step for how to display the result

Comment: Error Number: 1054
when i replace **** to my search variable ,i getting this error 
Unknown column 'DemoCompany' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE DemoCompany

Comment: @Abdulla may be your query should be `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name LIKE '%Demo%'`

Comment: i got the result using this query "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name LIKE '%Demo%'",but how to display in dropdown box

Answer (score 0):

This will give table names as an array.

```
$tabResults = $this->db->select('TABLE_NAME')
  ->from('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')
  ->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', 'database-name')
  ->like('TABLE_NAME', 'Demo')
  ->get()->result_array();
$tables = array_column($tabResults, 'TABLE_NAME');
```

Then to display them as a comma-separated list:

```
echo implode(', ', $tables);
```