# i want to show tables from my database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->query("show tables");    
$tables = $this->db->get();    
return $tables->result_array();
```

> Error Number: 1096
>   No tables used
>   SELECT *

Comment: **Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.**

Comment: `$this->db->list_tables()` use this query to list tables from you database

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151291/how-to-display-the-database-table-names-list-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `$this->db->list_tables()` to get all the tables name from database.

```
$tables = $this->db->list_tables();

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
        echo $table;
}
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Metadata](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/metadata.html)

Comment: @hasnain glad to help.Happy coding.

Comment: better not to add the duplicate answers, Bcz there is exact duplicate on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151291/how-to-display-the-database-table-names-list-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->get()` is a [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) method, and you're not using QB to create your query.

You should be calling `result_array()` directly on the `query()` return value, like this:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES");
$tables = $result->result_array();
```

This is obvious if you read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows).

... and yes, you could also use [list_tables()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=list_tables#CI_DB_driver::list_tables).